# SQL - cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql, constraints

I keep getting the error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`myWork`.`Bookingss`, CONSTRAINT `Bookingss_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
> (`CustomersID`) REFERENCES `Customers` (`CustomersID`))

I have spent a while researching as this is apart of a school assignment and can not seem to resolve the problem.

Here is my SQL code:

```
USE myWork ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Bookingss ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customers ;

CREATE TABLE myWork.Customers 
(
        CustomersID     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Surname         CHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
        FirstName       CHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
        Title           CHAR(10),
        DOB             DATE,
        HouseNumber     INT,
        StreetName      CHAR(30),
        Town            CHAR(30),
        PostCode        CHAR(9),
        Telephone       INT,
        
        PRIMARY KEY (CustomersID)
) ;

CREATE TABLE myWork.Bookingss
(
        BookingsID       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        CustomersID      INT NOT NULL,
        AdultsBooked     INT NOT NULL,
        ChildrenBooked   INT NOT NULL,
        Check_In         DATE,
        Check_Out        DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY (BookingsID),
        FOREIGN KEY (CustomersID) 
            REFERENCES myWork.Customers (CustomersID)
) ;


SHOW TABLES ;


INSERT INTO myWork.Bookingss ( CustomersID,   AdultsBooked , ChildrenBooked , Check_In , Check_Out )
VALUES ("1", "2", "3", "2022-04-10", "2022-04-13"  ) ;


INSERT INTO myWork.Customers ( Surname , FirstName , Title , DOB )
VALUES ( "smith" , "ryan" , "Mr" , "1998-02-16" ) ;

SELECT * FROM Customers , Bookingss;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of a _foreign key_? (Rhetorical question.)

Comment: Please check the description of the foreign key constraint. You cannot insert a value in FK-constrained column that is absent in the referenced column

Comment: You're trying to create a booking, which references a customer, before you create the customer. You can't do that, that's the point of the foreign key ***constraint***. A booking is only valid if it references a customer thst actually exists in the customer table. So, create the customers first... *(As and aside; stop quoting your integers. `1` is a number, but `"1"` isn't. And stop using `,` to join tables, use `JOIN` syntax, it's been around for 30 years, just enough time to adopt it?)*

Answer (score 0):

You got the order wrong and some challenges to overcome. You are trying to insert a booking first, and this with an id for a customer that does not yet exist in the customer table at that moment.

You have to insert the customer first, then use the customer's id to insert the booking for the customer (using his id).

And there is the first challenge. The customer id is an auto increment field. You would not know the id when you insert a customer in the table.

You would have to fetch the customer and use the id of that customer to insert a booking for the customer. How do you fetch the customer? Selecting the customer with a specific name surname and first name is not a correct choice, any other field (or composition of fields) that I see in the table definition is not a good choice neither.

You'd need to think further about a good solution. There are several options I could tell you about. But the appropriate solution depends on your assignment/context.

By the way, the last select clause may not deliver the result you expect. You are producing a cartesian product (every row of the first table with every row of the second table). What you probably want is a JOIN where you link the first table with the second table accordingly (e.g. using the primary key and the foreign key).